# Strange behaviour with a boundless box in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In the code below whenever I change the height value of the blue box, the height of the red box changes accordingly. However, changes to the width value of the blue box has no effect on the width of the red box. Why is it so?
Note that I commented out the size of the red box.

```
@Composable
fun ScreenSize() {
    Column(

        modifier = Modifier.size(400.dp)
    ) {
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                //.size(300.dp)
                .background(Color.Red),
            
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "mxwidth: $maxWidth, mnwidth: $minWidth," +
                        " mxheight: $maxHeight, mnheight: $minHeight",
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart)
            )

            BoxWithConstraints(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(width = 200.dp, height = 200.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "mxwidth: $maxWidth, mnwidth: $minWidth, mxheight: $maxHeight, mnheight: $minHeight",
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of the code:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Blue BoxWithConstraints inside Red BoxWithConstraints it's overlapping the red box. And as no width is defined for the red box it's being managed by the width of the text in it. If you'll remove/reduce the text the width of red box will reduce accordingly.

Also the width of red box is dependent on blue box too, currently it's occupying the max width of text or blue box